# Getting a div to appear with onclick addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am attempting to do an onclick event where the show class is added, however, I cannot get my `new-goal-container` to appear when 'Create new goal' is clicked.

I do not want this to be a toggle, simply an add class. As my code shows, I am trying to get this to do a quick fadeIn appearance with css. Is there a better approach to this, because now even though nothing is showing the div is still taking up space, which when the container is not visible, I want it to seem as if it doesn't exist.

```js
$("#new-goal-button").click(function() {
  $("#new-goal-container").addClass("show");
});
```

```css
#new-goal-container {
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.show {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new-goal-button">Create new goal</div>
<div id="new-goal-container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Goal Title">
  <textarea placeholder="Goal Description">
</div>
```

Comment: `textarea` is not closed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is due to an `id` selector being more specific than a `class` selector. Therefore, `opacity: 0` overrides `opacity: 1`. Add the `id` and `class` selector together to give them a higher specificity than the original `id` selector alone.

Also note that your `textarea` element needs a closing tag, the `transition` rule should ideally be on the base rule of the element and only apply to the `opacity` rule and finally the `-webkit-` vendor prefix is no longer required.

```js
$("#new-goal-button").click(function() {
  $("#new-goal-container").addClass("show");
});
```

```css
#new-goal-container {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
#new-goal-container.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new-goal-button">Create new goal</div>
<div id="new-goal-container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Goal Title">
  <textarea placeholder="Goal Description"></textarea>
</div>
```

Here's a working example in a jsFiddle too as SO Snippets seem to be broken at the moment:

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ky1pc40r/)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea how I can get the `new-goal-container` element to not take up space when it isn't showing?

Comment: Use `display: none` instead of `opacity: 0`.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it impossible to have the fade in effect then?

Comment: I just changed the container's height to 0 and then added the height I wanted it to be within the show class. Thanks for the help!